# Mocha doesn't wait for nodejs init to be done

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm trying to integration- and unit test with Mocha, but Mocha doesn't wait for any callback to be done (or in my case, promise to fulfill)...

One moment when I try to test, the promise get's fulfilled BEFORE the first integration test is done, the other moment it crashes...

server.js

```
const server = require('./app');

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('Starting server.');
    console.log('Displaying server information:');
    console.log(`Host: http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);    
});
```

app.js

```
require('babel/register');
/**
 * Make some commonly used directories known to the process env
 */
process.env.ROOT_DIR = __dirname;

/**
 * Setup Express server and the Express Router
 */
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const server = express();

// Parses the body for JSON object in the middleware so extra steps for
// parsing aren't required.
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


server.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('url called', req.originalUrl);
    next();
});

// This is the call which has the database set up in it
// This has a few generator functions in 'm
require('./init')(server);

/**
 * Export
 */
// Define routes on the server.
module.exports = server;
```

integration test (which is the first one that gets fired)

```
import should from 'should';
import supertest from 'supertest';
import server from '../../app';
import co from 'co';

let request = supertest(server); // Set request to context of the app.

describe('Index', function () {

    describe('GET /', function () {
        it('returns 200', co.wrap(function * (done) {
            const res = yield request
                .get('/');

            res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
        }));
    });

    describe('GET /this_is_not_a_valid_route_123456', function () {
        it('returns 404', function (done) {
            request
                .get('/this_is_not_a_valid_route_123456')
                .expect(404, done);
        });
    });
});
```

command:

```
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- ./test/ --recursive --compilers js:babel/register
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Screenshot of what happens:
(Init done should be BEFORE the 'Index GET /' and directly after 'Init config repo...')
[image]

Comment: You should show your test as well. And it doesn't sound like you are writing a unit test, rather an integration test.

Comment: It does both in 1 swoop :P I'll update my question, gimme a sec

Answer (score 0):

You can tell mocha to wait.

```
before(function (done) {
  if (server.listening) return done();
  server.on('listening', function() { done(); });
});
```

I'm not sure what's inside your `init` file but if you also want to wait for other events, you can add multiple `before` functions.